# Privoxy isn't saving to logfile

Tags: arch-linux, logs, privoxy

After installing privoxy I started it up and, after directing my browser to run through it as a proxy, I was presented with an error saying the following

```
"There is no Internet connection

There is something wrong with the proxy server, or the address is incorrect."
```

Fair enough, I decided to check the log file and see what is going on, but there is absolutely nothing in the log file.

Upon checking the config file, I see that I have the following settings

```
...
logdir /var/log/privoxy    
logfile logfile
debug     1 # Log the destination for each request Privoxy let through. See also debug 1024.
debug  1024 # Actions that are applied to all sites and maybe overruled later on.
debug  4096 # Startup banner and warnings
debug  8192 # Non-fatal errors
...
```

Alright, so it says that is should be logging to the file logfile in the directory /var/log/privoxy.
I check the permissions and find

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 privoxy privoxy            4096 Jan 31 16:18 privoxy
```

So it's not a permissions issue. I have uninstalled and reinstalled to no avail. I have no idea why it isn't working. It is logging to the system journal but I hate having to dig through that for stuff.

For context, I am running Arch Linux.

I found that if I manually start it via

```
sudo privoxy --user privoxy --no-daemon /etc/privoxy/config
```

that it runs just fine. So I have determined it is a systemd issue. Below is the default systemd file

```
[Unit]
Description=Privoxy Web Proxy With Advanced Filtering Capabilities
After=network.target

[Service]
User=privoxy
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/privoxy --no-daemon /etc/privoxy/config
PrivateDevices=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a packaging issue: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/54570

Have a look at: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7198

Try this systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Privoxy Web Proxy With Advanced Filtering Capabilities   
After=network.target   

[Service]
#User=privoxy
#Type=simple
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/privoxy --no-daemon /etc/privoxy/config
#PrivateDevices=yes

Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/privoxy.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/privoxy --pidfile /var/run/privoxy.pid --user privoxy.privoxy /etc/privoxy/config
ExecStop=/usr/bin/rm /var/run/privoxy.pid
SuccessExitStatus=15
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/privoxy/logfile
StandardError=file:/var/log/privoxy/logfile

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/privoxy

Comment: I am still struggling with this (as in, still to this day).

Thank you for this!